# mikrotik: пропал маршрут по умолчанию

Tags: mikrotik, routeros

Не знаю, по адресу ли я задаю вопрос (SO вроде как больше для программистов), но может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой и знает её решение (ну или может подсказать, куда копать).

Проблема, в общем, такая: сегодня с утра обнаружил, что интернет пропал. Стал разбираться, и выяснил, что на моём роутере Mikrotik RB750 из списка маршрутов куда-то делся маршрут по умолчанию. Маршруты по локальной сети есть, маршрут до сети провайдера есть, а маршрут 0.0.0.0/0 ночью по непонятной причине просто испарился! В логах - тишина. Переполучение настроек по dhcp результатов не дало. Помог ребут. Я пока не знаю, разовая эта проблема, или регулярная (этот роутер у меня работает меньше недели), но в любом случае так быть не должно! Конфигурация стандартная (настраивал после сброса), никаких VPN и прочего такого нет, dhcp-клиент только один, и он на интерфейсе ether1 (как и требуется). Поговорил с двумя своими знакомыми, кто разбирается в микротах, но те сказали, что ни разу с такой проблемой не сталкивались. Гугление тоже ничего не даёт (или я неправильно гуглю).

Информация по системе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, я рад любым вашим советам по поводу (кроме совета выкинуть это старьё на помойку)...

Comment: ремонтные работы у провайдера такое делают. Недавно у меня туннель ipv6 упал. говорят, что что-то переделывали и шось упало. Но до сих пор DHCPv6 так и не пашет. чтобы маршрут 0.0. не испарялся, сделайте его статическим.

Comment: @AlexGlebe интересно, что там такое могут делать у провайдера, чтобы потерялись стандартные динамические маршруты... В общем, буду наблюдать периодичность данной проблемы. Но и на роутер есть большие подозрения. Например, позапрошлой ночью он бутнулся из-за падения какого-то критически важного процесса, о чём я прочитал в логах опять таки с утра. Это может быть зловред в ядре? Тут ведь в чём нюанс, роутер мне достался б/у, неизвестно, что там на нём ставили/прошивали. На заводские перед настройкой я его, естественно, сбрасывал, и прошивку обновлял. Но всё же...